# Android: BigDecimal to Float loss of data

Tags: android, bigdecimal

I store a variable in sqlite db as REAL but in my app I need to use it as BigDecimal.
The problem is, I am not able to save my BigDecimal variable to my sqlite without converting it to float or double.

so I do the following:

```
bigDecimal.floatValue();
```

but by doing that a loss of precision occurs.

for example
if I put to my editText from which I get the variable: 123456789 
after converting it from bigDecimal to float I get : 123456792

The same happens if I try to cast bigdecimal to string:

```
String.valueOf(bigDecimal);
```

the problem occurs ONLY if the variable which I put is at least 8 digits long.
It behaves the same way if its a decimal number and the numbers differ always after the seven digit.

is that a normal behaviour ? how to avoid it?

Comment: You should convert bigDecimal to Double and not to Float

Comment: SQLite [REAL](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_2) is a 64 bit IEEE floating point number. A double in Java notation. You'll lose precision as soon as you store it to the db. Use strings instead (or blobs).

Comment: FWIW, instead of `String.valueOf(bigDecimal)` try `bigDecimal.toPlainString()`.

Comment: The precision of a float is 6-7 digits, so an 8 digit value wil have to be rounded to the nearest value a float can represent. A float only has 24 bits to represent the value, and 123456789 is 27 bits in size, so the value has to be rounded down to 24 bits (more or less by chopping off the last 3 bits and then rounding the resulting value) while the exponent is incremented by 3 (which is like a multiplication by 8).

Comment: converting to double doesnt change anything.
bigDecimal.toPlainString() ; it helps when used only before saving to db. after that problem still exists.
the only way i didnt yet try is to change the column in database from float to string, because it would require to do a lot of changes.
but perhaps it will be necessary if no better answer shows up